# How to find the height of the individual slides of a carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a carousel in which there are three slides the markup is something like this below

```
<div id="corpsite-carousel">
<div class="slide">
<!-- slide 1 content  -->
</div>
<div class="slide">
<!-- slide 2 content -->
</div>
<div class="slide">
<!-- slide 3 content  -->
</div>
<div class="controls">
</div>
</div>
```

So there are three slides and each has a varying length of content(which includes text and images), after implementation, I see each slide to have its own height based on the content inside it which makes it a very bad user experience (as by changing the slides the sliding bullet controls change up and down). I am trying to set the height of the slides to the slide whose height is the highest.

I am trying using  the following jquery code to  find the height of each slide

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var slides = $('#corpsite-carousel .cmp-carousel__item');
 var heightsArr
 console.log(slides);
 slides.each(funiction(i){
   var height = $(this).innerHeight();
   console.log(height)
 })
})
```

but the console shows me the height of the first slide which is correct but the rest 2 slides heights are not correct(i checked in the dom after sliding and checked the height of each slide) I think this is because the slide 2 and 3 are not available yet on the screen. what should be the approach or the best method to set the height of the slides.

Comment: Try by setting max-height  with some default value you like to allocate slides  using css .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little sleight of hand - something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 maxHeight = 0 ;
 var slides = $('#corpsite-carousel .cmp-carousel__item');
 var heightsArr
 console.log(slides);
 slides.each(function(i){
   maxHeight = Math.max( maxHeight, quickMeasure($(this)));
 })
})

function quickMeasure(el) {
  var previousCss  = el.attr("style");

  el.css({
    position:   'absolute', // Optional if #myDiv is already absolute
    visibility: 'hidden',
    display:    'block'
  });

  theHeight = $(el).height();

  el.attr("style", previousCss ? previousCss : "");
  return theHeight
}
```